# Android Issue with 2 test devices and layout folders

Tags: android, layout

I am using two devices for testing: **Samsung Galaxy Note 4** and **LG Venice (LG730)**. The relevant specs for both are:

**Note 4**

- 5.7 inch screen
- 2560 x 1440

**LG Venice**

- 4.3 inch screen
- 800 x 400

I have a layout in the following folders: `layout-small`, `layout-normal`, `layout-large`, `layout-xlarge`. The issue is that both devices are using the layout in `layout-normal`. However, since the resolutions are so different, elements are cut off on the LG Venice when they look correct on the Note 4. Likewise, when elements look correct on the LG Venice, there is a LOT of blank space on the Note 4.

I am using LinearLayouts and RelativeLayouts, no AbsoluteLayouts.
Am I setting up the folders incorrectly?

Here is the layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rel_large_control"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="true"

android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/ivAlbumArt_lrg"
    android:layout_width="300dip"
    android:layout_height="300dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:src="@drawable/placeholder" />


<LinearLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"

    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Previous Button -->


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSong_lrg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivAlbumArt_lrg"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center"

        android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"

        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="large" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvArtist_lrg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvSong_lrg"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvSong_lrg"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvSong_lrg"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvSong_lrg"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/md_blue_grey_400"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:autoText="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvAlbum_lrg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvArtist_lrg"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvArtist_lrg"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvArtist_lrg"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvArtist_lrg"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fadingEdge="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/md_blue_grey_400"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:autoText="true" />


</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/songProgressBar_lrg"
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:maxHeight="5dip"

        android:minHeight="5dip"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:paddingEnd="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seek_handler" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvElapsedTime_lrg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/songProgressBar_lrg"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/songProgressBar_lrg"
        android:layout_below="@+id/songProgressBar_lrg"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"


        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="00:00:00"
        android:textColor="@color/md_light_green_A700"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTotalTime_lrg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/songProgressBar_lrg"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/songProgressBar_lrg"
        android:layout_below="@+id/songProgressBar_lrg"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="00:00:00"
        android:textColor="@color/md_blue_grey_400"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</RelativeLayout>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnShuffle_lrg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/tvArtist_lrg"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnPrevious_lrg"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btnPrevious_lrg"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_shuffle" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnPrevious_lrg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/btnShuffle_lrg"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnPlay_lrg"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/btnPlay_lrg"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_previous" />
    <!-- Play Button -->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnPlay_lrg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/btnShuffle_lrg"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_play" />
    <!-- Next Button -->
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnNext_lrg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/btnShuffle_lrg"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnPlay_lrg"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_next" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btnRepeat_lrg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/btnShuffle_lrg"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnNext_lrg"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_repeat" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can we see your layout file in layout-normal?

Comment: are you using code to check the device size, pixel ratio? anyway i wouldnt worry about it too much. when you post your app on google play store you can target your app to specific devices so there is no need for different layouts to match device size on a single app. Just change the layout for specific device)s) so it looks ok and upload that version to target those devices and repeat that process for other types of devices